# How to compute the slope of random set using the bootstrap method?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scipy.stats

Somehow, the scipy.stats.bootstrap is not working in my Jupyter notebook. Therefore, I decide to write a sample function for bootstrap estimation.

**Here is what I did.**

```py
def bootstrap(x, Nboot, statfun):
    '''Bootstrap code'''
    x = np.array(x)
    
    resampled_stat = []
    for k in range(Nboot):
        index = np.random.randint(0, len(x), len(x))
        sample = x[index]
        bstatistic = statfun(sample)
        resampled_stat.append(bstatistic)
        
    return np.array(resampled_stat)
```

**Data Set:**

```
data=(0.045494, 0.065669, 0.073061, 0.104542, 0.296978, 0.498353, 0.503342, 0.515458, 0.660300, 0.663664, 0.677255, 0.724817, 0.805800, 0.899355, 0.987775, 2.121619, 2.165055, 2.196833, 3.265653, 3.479858, 8.702472, 10.070092, 10.720080, 12.896169, 12.912647, 14.244361, 14.287428, 17.337397, 18.903783, 20.940314, 21.404639, 22.234169)
result=bootstrap(data, 1000, np.mean)
```

So far, my script working well, but I need to modify this script for the following tasks:

1. How to add the option of with and without replacement.
2. How to play around the window length, for example, I want to add an option of with length 30 points bootstrap or 50, or 100 etc. that can make this more flexible.
3. last thing is most important, I want to compute the slop [number of observation will be used as x and y is the bootstrap sample, e.g. if the length of bootstrap window is 30 then x is an array from 1 to 30, and we will plot x verses bootstrap sample to compute slope]   for each random resampling iteration along with the confidence interval.

May someone suggest how can I fix this, or any other possible approach to complete this task.

Comment: For slope, don't you need two variables?  Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output.  Also, bootstrapping is, by definition, sampling *with* replacement ([Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics))).

Comment: AlexK, for slope the x-parameter is the number of data points and y is the bootstrap sample. For example, if I set 30 as the length of bootstrap sample, the x is an array from 1 to 30. So we will plot the bootstrap sample against the x array.

Answer (score 0):

> May someone suggest how can I fix this, or **any other possible approach to complete this task**.

It sounds like you are interested in bootstrapping a confidence interval of a slope. You stated that "`scipy.stats.bootstrap` is not working", but `bootstrap` can only work as well as the instructions it is given. I suspect that there was a problem with the instructions.

Here is code for performing the task as I understand it:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats, optimize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
rng = np.random.default_rng(8483546393569)

# Generate data
x = np.arange(1, 31)
y = 2*x + rng.normal(size=30)

# Define statistic (slow, but conceptually simple)
def f(x, m):
  return m * x

def statistic(x, y):
  return optimize.curve_fit(f, x, y)[0][0]

# Call scipy.stats.bootstrap
res = stats.bootstrap((x, y), statistic, paired=True)
res.confidence_interval
# ConfidenceInterval(low=1.9662687286306075, high=2.0001682618081906)

# Plot the bootstrap distribution
plt.hist(res.bootstrap_distribution, bins=50)
plt.xlabel('fitted slope')
plt.ylabel('frequency')
plt.title('Histogram of bootstrap distribution of slopes')
```

[image]

I expect that the most common mistake in this application would be to forget to include `paired=True`, which is important because corresponding `x` and `y` values need to stick together as pairs when resampling.